# How to export Elasticsearch Index to Folder Inside GCS Bucket Using Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-7, google-cloud-storage

I am using logstash and copying index from elastic search and uploading it to GCS Bucket using below .conf file:

```
input {

 elasticsearch {

    hosts => "localhost:9200"

    index => "test"


    query => '

    {
    "_source": ["field1","field2"],

    "query": {

    "match_all": {}

    }
    filter {
    mutate {
        rename => {
            "field1" => "test1"
            "field2" => "test2"
        }
      }
     }

    }

  '

  }

}


output {
   google_cloud_storage {
   codec => csv {
    include_headers => true
    columns => [ "test1", "test2" ]
   }
     bucket => "bucketName"
     json_key_file => "creds.json"
     temp_directory => "/tmp"
     log_file_prefix => "logstash_gcs"
     max_file_size_kbytes => 1024
     date_pattern => "%Y-%m-%dT%H:00"
     flush_interval_secs => 600
     gzip => false
     uploader_interval_secs => 600
     include_uuid => true
     include_hostname => true
   }
}
```

**However i am not able to upload file from elastic search to folder inside GCS Bucket, have tried below format it didn't work:
bucket => "bucketName/folderName"** .

When I tried to add the folder the log just showed "Uploading file...", but the file was not uploaded

Comment: Bucket accepts only value type [`string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-google_cloud_storage.html#plugins-outputs-google_cloud_storage-bucket). Can you try using an escape sequence based on this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration-file-structure.html#_escape_sequences)?

Comment: Hi @Robert G, Thanks for your response , it didn't work even after escaping sequence.